# Win32_LogicalDisk fails for floppies

Tags: .net, wmi

Using an idea from Bob King idea I wrote the following method.

It works great on CD's, removable drives, regular drives.

However for a floppy it always return "Not Available". Any ideas?

```
public static void TestFloppy( char driveLetter ) {
    using( var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(  @"SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID = '" + driveLetter + ":'" ) )
    using( var logicalDisks = searcher.Get() ) {
        foreach( ManagementObject logicalDisk in logicalDisks ) {  
          var fs = logicalDisk[ "FreeSpace" ];
            Console.WriteLine( "FreeSpace = " + ( fs ?? "Not Available" ) );
            logicalDisk.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that I don't have a better answer, but I used to do the same thing (use the ManagementObjectSearcher) and found that everytime the code ran the floppy drive would do some sort of seek/init sequence.

So instead I changed to the below and interate:

```
ManagementClass comp = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath(obj), null);
comp.Get();
objs = comp.GetInstances();
```

I want to say this is a known bug in WMI but unfortunately the code comments don't leave any hints :(